# Error counting Total documents in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I wanted to get the total record of documents in my collections and I have the following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const appUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
FullName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Full name is required'],             
    },   
Username: { 
type: String,
lowercase: true, 
},

UserType: { 
type: String,
enum: ['Local', 'Foreign'],
default: 'Local'
}
}, {
toJSON: {
virtuals: true, 
getter: true
},
toObject: {
virtuals: true
}
});

appUserSchema.virtual('TotalAppUsers').get(async function(){
   AppUser.countDocuments({}, function(err, total) {
    console.log('Total users is ' + total);
    return total;
}) 
})

appUserSchema.virtual('TotalLocalUsers').get(async function(){
   AppUser.countDocuments({UserType: 'Local'}, function(err, total) {
    console.log('Total local user is ' + total);
    return total;
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', appUserSchema);

    module.exports = {mongoose, User}


i successfully fetched all collection documents but the virtuals are empty, they returned empty with the following error in the console:

 const err = new MongooseError('Query was already executed: ' + str);
                  ^

MongooseError: Query was already executed: AppUser.count({ UserType: 'Bonded Terminal' })
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _count] (C:\Users\projects\\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:21:19) at C:\Users\projects\node_modules\kareem\index.js:367:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  originalStack: 'Error\n' +
```

***My Expectation

a) I want to get the total number of documents in the document

b) I want to get the total number of documents in the document where UserType field is Local.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is because you are trying to use the AppUser model within the virtuals of the appUserSchema, but you haven't defined the AppUser model yet. Instead, you should use the this.model('User') method to access the model within the virtuals. Here's the corrected code:

Virtuals and Callbacks: The primary issue is that you're trying to use callbacks within the virtual getters. The countDocuments function doesn't return a value directly; it works with callbacks or promises. When you use it with a callback, you can't return the count value from the virtual function.

[image: Even if you write code correctly, your promises will not be resolved when virtual fields are computed]

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const appUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    FullName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Full name is required'],             
    },   
    Username: { 
        type: String,
        lowercase: true, 
    },
    UserType: { 
        type: String,
        enum: ['Local', 'Foreign'],
        default: 'Local'
    }
}, {
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true, 
        getters: true
    },
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    }
});

appUserSchema.virtual('TotalAppUsers').get(async function(){
    const total = await this.model('User').countDocuments({});
    console.log('Total users is ' + total);
    return total;
});

appUserSchema.virtual('TotalLocalUsers').get(async function(){
    const total = await this.model('User').countDocuments({ UserType: 'Local' });
    console.log('Total local users is ' + total);
    return total;
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', appUserSchema);

module.exports = { mongoose, User };
```

Comment: The result of TotalAppUsers and TotalLocalUser showed in console.log but it didn't display the total as part of user response data sent back. I mean if you try to display the TotalAppUsers and the TotalLocalUser field(virtual field) from the "user" response object, the total is not displayed but it displayed on console.

Comment: It is being displayed in the console because that computation is Promise (which will be resolved in the future). When a user response is generated it will be a promise yet to be resolved.

Comment: If it would not display as virtual columns then there is no point using it. I actually wanted to use it in Model rather than using it in controller. I see it displayed in console but it is not displaying as a virtual column value. I want a situation where the value will be displayed as virtual column because I will use it in frontend. I don't want to send it through controller because i want the total value to change automatically while the other fields value increases or decreases.